# Hashcode to check uniqueness in a string array

Tags: c#, .net, linq, hashcode, gethashcode

I am storing large number of arrays of data into a List, however, I don't want to store the data if it already exists in my list - the order of the data doesn't matter. I figured using GetHashCode to generate a hashcode would be appropriate because it was *supposed* to not care about order. However, what I found with a simple test below is that for the first two string[] a1 and a2 it generates a different hashcode.

Can I not utilize this method of checking? Can someone suggest a better way to check please?

```
        string[] a1 = { "cat", "bird", "dog" };
        string[] a2 = { "cat", "dog", "bird" };
        string[] a3 = { "cat", "fish", "dog" };

        Console.WriteLine(a1.GetHashCode());
        Console.WriteLine(a2.GetHashCode());
        Console.WriteLine(a3.GetHashCode());
```

the results from the above test produces three different hashcode results.

Ideally, I would have liked to see the same Hashcode for a1 and a2...so I am looking for something that would allow me to quickly check if those strings already exist.

Comment: Use a Dictionary<string> or HashMap

Comment: You can't use `GetHashCode` here because 1. `GetHashCode` on array does care about order of elements. 2. `GetHashCode` only looks at last 8 elements of the array.

Comment: Mitch - did search, clearly didn't a solution. Sten - can you elaborate what you mean by dictionary/hashmap...not sure how a key/value pair will solve my dilemma

Comment: I'm pretty sure array's implementation of  `GetHashCode()` doesn't actually check the contents in any way.  So references to distinct but content equivalent arrays will produce different HashCodes.

Comment: Marcin - is there an alternative please?

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Are you certain about #2?  If I create two arrays with 3 equal members they return different hash codes.  Since there's no overload it used `Object.GetHashCode`, correct?

Comment: hmm, there is `Array.GetHashCode` method in sourceof.net. I would expect this one to be used.

Comment: @MarcinJuraszek Do you mean the `int IStructuralEquatable.GetHashCode(IEqualityComparer comparer)` method? It's an explicit interface method implementation (and it also has a parameter), it won't be called on an `Array` variable. `Array` doesn't override `object.GetHashCode()`. It uses the `object` implementation, returning a pseudo-random number first time it's called on an instance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your arrays aren't equal, by the standard used by arrays for determining equality. The standard used by arrays for determining equality is that two separately created arrays are *never* equal.

If you want separately created collections with equal elements to compare as equal, then use a collection type which supports that.

I recommend `HashSet<T>`, in your case `HashSet<string>`. It doesn't provide the `GetHashCode()` and `Equals()` behaviour you want directly, but it has a [`CreateSetComparer()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb335475%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method that provides you with a helper class that *does* give you hash code and comparer methods that do what you want.

Just remember that you cannot use this for a quick equality check. You can only use this for a quick *inequality* check. Two objects that are not equal may still have the same hash code, basically by random chance. It's only when the hash codes aren't equal that you can skip the equality check.

Comment: It doesn't even strictly need to be by random chance.  It's only required that objects that are equal produce the same hashcode, all objects of a particular type returning the same hash code technically satisfies that.

Comment: @TheInnerLight Yes, that's another alternative, though that's such a poor implementation (unless all objects of that type are actually supposed to compare as equal, in which case your comment doesn't apply) that I'd recommend avoiding any class that has that property, as it's likely to have more serious bugs as well. :)

Comment: Oh yeah it's horrific, I definitely don't recommend that behaviour for one second.  My comment was definitely not an endorsement of writing classes in that way.  It was just to outline the absolute worst possible case.

Comment: @hvd with the CreateSetComparer() class, do I just have to overload and write my own criteria or does it automatically perform a compare? Looking for a quick easy solution here

Comment: @Reza `CreateSetComparer()` is a method, not a class. It does use a class, but you cannot access that class directly. Not only don't you have to overload or override anything, there isn't any way to overload or override anything.

Answer (score 0):

If you say a1.[GetHashCode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.object.gethashcode.aspx)(), this will [always generate a new hash code for you](https://dotnetfiddle.net/vOlIBA):

```
using System;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        string[] a1 = { "cat", "bird", "dog" };
        string[] a2 = { "cat", "dog", "bird" };
        string[] a3 = { "cat", "fish", "dog" };

        Console.WriteLine(a1.GetHashCode());
        Console.WriteLine(a2.GetHashCode());
        Console.WriteLine(a3.GetHashCode());
    }
}
```